# Scrapy on Ubuntu web server getting 417 error

Tags: scrapy

I have been developing a crawling script for a number of news websites and using Scrapy to handle the logic.

When I run my script on an Ubuntu web server (Digital Ocean, if that helps), a lot of the websites that return 200 on my local machine turn out to be 417 instead.

I was wondering how I should fix this, if it is a problem at all? I'm actually not quite sure if it is affecting the final output, but it seems like it has been.

Some of my own research has turned up:

- http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E417.html . I've tried adding an Expect header to my requests, which hasn't worked
- I've heard that it might be a problem with HTTP 1.1 vs 1.0? EDIT: Nope. Scrapy's HTTPDownloaderHandler automatically chooses 1.1 if it is available

Comment: Have you tried a minimal test in your DOc Ubuntu machine? like deploying a simple google scrape spider and running it?

Comment: Also have you tried to see what request is Scrapy sending in that remote environment?

Comment: Are you sure you have same versions of all the libs that you are using in your local? I mean if it works in your local, there must be a difference, you should check Scrapy and its dependencies above all

Comment: Hey @GermanRosales: yes, I've run minimal tests to show that what works on my local machine is clearly a 417 on the Ubuntu machine. What do you mean "what request is Scrapy sending in that remote environment"? It is the same get request with presumably the same settings (as in settings.py). I am currently updating all dependencies...

Comment: Yes, normally it would send the same request, with the same headers and body, but as you are getting a different response from the server it would healthy to check the request for diff between the 2 environments

Comment: Both use {'Accept-Language': ['en'], 'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip,deflate'], 'Accept': ['text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'], 'User-Agent': ['Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org)']}

Comment: This may sound obvious but Are you able to browse that site from your server, using lynx?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that! Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using lynx for one of the websites and it showed a 417 "This connection has been rate limited due to suspected robot activity. If you believe this is an error please click here." It's odd that this doesn't show up on my computer!

Comment: Maybe they blocked your public ip or it was already blocked, if you have dynamic ip you can try rebooting the instance and have your bot go easier on the site, I will include some good practices in an answer later today

Answer (score 0):

417 is the error a web server gives you when your client says it expects content-types a,b,c, but the content that the server could deliver doesn't match any of these types.

This looks like a scrapy bug or, more likely, misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems either your public ip address was already banned or was banned while you scraped by the web server of the page you want to scrape. For the first situation you can reboot your instance to get a new public ip (at least this works on Amazon). For the second scenario, here are some tips from the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned) to avoid this situation:

- rotate your user agent from a pool of well-known ones from browsers
  (google around to get a list of them)
- disable cookies (see COOKIES_ENABLED) as some sites may use cookies to spot bot behaviour
- use download delays (2 or higher). See DOWNLOAD_DELAY setting.
- if possible, use Google cache to fetch pages, instead of hitting the
  sites directly
- use a pool of rotating IPs. For example, the free Tor
  project or paid services like ProxyMesh
- use a highly distributed downloader that circumvents bans internally, so you can just focus on parsing clean pages. One example of such downloaders is Crawlera

Additionally, you can reduce [concurrent requests](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) settings in your spider, that worked once for me.